# No Instance of this constructor

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

So I'm making a Camera class for an OpenGL program, and I've come across a blip with the basic C++ code, where I'm not allowed to initialize it with values. My implementation is below:

```
class Camera{

public:
    Camera();
    Camera(vec3 pos(), vec3 fron(), vec3 up(), GLfloat y, GLfloat p, GLfloat r);

    ...
};

Camera::Camera(vec3 pos(), vec3 fron(), vec3 up(), GLfloat y, GLfloat p, GLfloat r)
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

The rest is in my main:

```
int main(){

    GLfloat lastx = width/2.0f;
    GLfloat lasty = height/2.0f; 
    GLfloat yaw = 90.0f;  //yaw set to -90 because yaw of 0.0 points to right or something wierd happens in euler angles
    GLfloat pitch = 0.0f;
    vec3 camerapos = vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, -10.0f);
    vec3 camerafront = vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    vec3 cameraup = vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Camera cam(camerapos, camerafront, cameraup, yaw, pitch, GLfloat(0.0f));
}
```

Strangely enough, I tried to initialise it empty, and populate it (with the same function, mind you), but I called it init() instead. At that point, I was told that the variable must have a Classtype.

Anything glaringly obvious staring me in the face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this declaration:

```
Camera(vec3 pos(), vec3 fron(), vec3 up(), GLfloat y, GLfloat p, GLfloat r);
```

you declared `pos`, `fron` and `up` as functions (taking no parameters and returning `vec3`).

Remove the parentheses (in both declaration and definition):

```
Camera(vec3 pos, vec3 fron, vec3 up, GLfloat y, GLfloat p, GLfloat r);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the most vexing parse; it's just how function declarations are. Like `int a();` isn't MVP, just vexing.

Comment: *facepalms* God I'm tired, pretty sure I pointed this same mistake out to a friend only last week. That's it working perfectly now, yer a star.